# Add shadow to a Label - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I would like to add drop shadow to a Label. This label is overlapped in the Page, like an always visible control that opens a filtering page.

Please find a gif attached with my screen:

[image: My app]

Here's my XAML:

```
<!-- **** Filter button **** -->
<Label
    Margin="0,0,10,10"
    WidthRequest="50"
    HeightRequest="50"
    HorizontalOptions="End"
    VerticalOptions="End"
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
    FontSize="30"   
    Style="{DynamicResource FilterAction}"
    Text="&#xf0b0;"
    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ComplementColor}"
    FontFamily="{x:Static artina:FontAwesome.FontName}"
    TextColor="White">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding btn_open_filter_businesses_click}" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>

<templates:Badge 

    BadgeText="{Binding number_of_filters_selected}" 
    BadgeTextColor="White"  
    BadgeBackgroundColor="#1DBDFF"
    HorizontalOptions="End"
    VerticalOptions="End"
    TranslationX="-4"
    TranslationY="-4"
    IsVisible="{Binding number_of_filters_selected, Converter={StaticResource filterVis}"
    x:Name="filtersCountBagde">
    <templates:Badge.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding btn_open_filter_businesses_click}" />
    </templates:Badge.GestureRecognizers>
</templates:Badge>
```

I would like something like Gmail, find the example below:

[image: Example]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Xamarin Effects to achieve a shadow on your button. There is a code sample that you can download here which should get you started:

[Shadow Effect](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Effects/ShadowEffect/)

It will involve creating platform-specific implementations for your shadow.

You could also try [the idea put forward in this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743966/how-do-you-create-a-drop-shadow-in-xamarin-forms).